# Moving Java application between two or more computers

Tags: java, distributed-computing

I am looking for a way to do an apparently simple thing:

Suppose I am running an application on PC1. This application writes numbers from 1 to 1000 on screen.

At some point (for example when the application is writing the number 500) I want to stop the execution on the PC1 and continue it from the same number on PC2.

So: 
PC1:
1
2
...
499
500
STOP

PC2:
500
501
...
999
1000

Is there a way to do this kind of migration transparently?

I know that a possible solution is to write the stop number in a txt file, send this file to PC2 and start from that number but I am looking for a smarter way.
Java could be a good language to do this

Every suggest is accepted!

Comment: Flagged as too broad. You're basically asking for a 101 on distributed computing / Java networking.

Comment: [You can use RMI.](http://infolab.stanford.edu/CHAIMS/Doc/Details/Protocols/rmi/rmi_description.html)

Comment: @wonderb0lt, what is a "101 on distributed computing"?

Comment: @MarcoRiezzo A beginner's course.

Answer (score 0):

Writing the stop number in a txt file is smartest way, given the circumstances.

On a side note, a good language to do this would be smalltalk where you just transfer the whole JVM heap/stack to another computer and continue.

Comment: Can you link me an example that explains how to do that with smalltalk??